How to test deserialization in calls to Contentful's GetEntries?
I am adding a new content model in Contentful, and I'm using Contentful's .NET SDK to retrieve its entries.  In the past I've experienced problems migrating from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json, including problems triggered by enabling nullable reference types, which caused many unexpected problems with model validation and properties that were implicitly optional.
I want to be able to avoid those in the future, and for that I wanted to write unit tests that verify that calls to Contentful's GetEntry and GetEntries don't start to blow up unexpectedly at the deserialization stage just because a package was updated.  However, this sort of usecase doesn't seem to be supported by Contentful's .NET SDK.
So, is there any way to write unit tests that mock the response from Contentful's API and verify that the deserialization step in Contentful's .NET SDK still works?

This is exactly what the SDKs unit tests does. You could achieve this by doing something similar. Setup a fake message handler that gets a response from a file similar to: https://github.com/contentful/contentful.net/blob/master/Contentful.Core.Tests/ClientTestsBase.cs#L38
Setup an HttpClient with this custom message handler similar to this:
 var httpClient = new HttpClient(_handler);
            var client = new ContentfulClient(httpClient, "444", "", "435");
            _handler.Response = GetResponseFromFile(@"SampleEntries.json");

Make your call and verify that the response gets deserialized correctly within the context of your application.
